# When i empty the trash automatically the files tab opens. How can i stop this?

Tags: nautilus, delete, trash

I press right click on the trash icon on the left corner of my screen and I chose "empty trash..."
Then a pop-up appears that says "Empty all items from trash?" and together with that, a window of *Files (Nautilus)* opens automatically, which is very annoying!
Even if i already have one window open, it opens another one and i have to close it to continue!

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [bug in `nautilus` 3.14.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1451495).

As of now, no `nautilus` updates available, and no workarounds suggested within the bug report; if you really want to fix this, downgrading `nautilus` should do.